# Read only DateTimeField won't render in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following django model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I also have the following django admin class:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['title', 'body']
    readonly_fields = ['created_date']
    list_display = ['title', 'body', 'created_date']
```

In the django admin app I can see the `created_date` field in my Article list:

[image]

But for the life of me I can't get the `created_date` field to render (as a read only field) when I open an Article:

[image]

I got the impression from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) and from googling around that adding Article's `created_date` field to `readonly_fields` would allow this to happen even if I had set `auto_now_add` to True on a `DateTimeField`.

Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

I'm using django 1.4.2.

Comment: If it is read-only (and thus can't be changed), why do you need to have it on the "Change article" page?

Comment: @DavidRobinson - so that I can display when the article was originally created.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, the `change` page also serves as the object detail view page. Create/Read/Update is all one template/form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've specified `fields`, you need to add the field to `fields`.

> however, when you specify ModelAdmin.fields or ModelAdmin.fieldsets the read-only fields must be present to be shown (they are ignored otherwise).

The `auto_now` magic has gotten me a few times.

Comment: Ah!...when I first tried this I didn't know about `readonly_fields` and had originally added `created_date` to `fields`. Of course it threw an exception and I removed it. Then I discovered `readonly_fields` but hadn't thought to re-add the field back into the `fields` list assuming wrongly that I'd still get an exception. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem.. it's definitely a piece of django I found particularly magical. I think at one point I simply removed it and did the usual save() override as opposed to reading into it.